# soon vs before long in past sentences

Tags: difference

A similar question is already asked, but I would like to get further information about this.

> He was sick in bed for five days.  He couldn't eat anything.  But on the sixth day, his doctor allowed him to walk around the room.  **Before long**, he became able to have food, though he could have only liquid at first.

> He was sick in bed for five days.  He couldn't eat anything.  But on the sixth day, his doctor allowed him to walk around the room.  **Soon**, he became able to have food, though he could have only liquid at first.

These seem different to me.  I feel the first one expresses a change that was caused without his intention, because in my language so.  Is there any nuance between them?

**supplement:**
I learned that "before long" is more poetic than "soon" according to another post concerning these two expressions. There are similar (in meanings) two words in my language too, and "before long" is more poetic than "soon" in my language too.

In Merriam-Webster dictionary I found that

> "soon" has several [meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soon): "before long," "speedily," "willingly," "before the usual time," and "immediately."

On the other hand,

> "before long" is explained as ["in the near future"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before%20long) or "soon."

So, I suppose "soon" might cover wider range of meanings than "before long."

I would like to suggest other examples, which seem very different for me when I translate them into my language.

> He started eating lunch **soon** after it was served.

> The dog looked hesitant at first but started eating it **before long**.

I feel that in these two sentences "soon" and "before long" are not interchangeable.

"Soon" is sometimes equal to the word "immediately" while "before long" is not.  Am I right??

Comment: I don't see any difference. **Before long** just means 'before a long time had elapsed'. Anyway, the speed of recovery from an illness is outside the patient's control (though a positive attitude helps).

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, I see!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: I agree, I don't feel a difference between these two in English, but I'm not sure that I could explain why 

Comment: Please link to the previous question. Also, what research have you done about those phrases? (For example, M-W online includes an entry for "before long"; that would be one place to look.)

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon Thank you so much!!

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I see, thank you very much!  I will.